# Call function in a row white exporting to CSV - VueJS (vue-json-csv)

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, export-to-csv

I have a set of data, some of them are being retrieved from Vuex store and are getting exported to csv. For example:

```
 json_data: [
                    {
                        'N0' : '1', 
                        'Parameters':'Scenario Name',
                        'Values':`${this.$store.state.scenario.scenario}`,
                    },
```

But some values are bring printed using this function getEvents(). They are printed, but **how do you export those values to a row as its called in a loop and how do you pass that function as value to export it.**

```
getEvent(){
for (let evt in this.$store.state.scenario.environment.events){
   evt += evt + ', ';
     }
     return evts;
 }
```

I want to export the multiple values which this loop returns, to csv.
Please do help!